# Exporting spark executor jmx metrics for multiple executors running in same machine

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, jmx-exporter

I am trying to scrape metrics for spark driver and executor using javaagent with below options. I have Prometheus in kubernetes cluster and I am running this spark application outside the kubernetes cluster.

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:/opt/clkd/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=53700:executor_pattern.yaml
```

but I got below exception since both executors running on the same machine

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use ....
```

I see many have posted the same question but I couldn't find the answer. Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to switch from the pull-based monitoring, to push-based monitoring.  For things, such as Spark jobs it makes more sense, as they aren't running all the time.  For that you have some alternatives:

- Spark Prometheus Sink from Banzai Cloud as outlined in their [blog post](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/spark-prometheus-sink/)
- Setup GraphiteSink as described in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/monitoring.html), and point it to the https://github.com/prometheus/graphite_exporter, and then **scrape** metrics from that exporter

---

Initial answer:

You can't have 2 processes listening on the same port, so just bind Prometheus from different jobs onto the different ports. Port is the number after the `jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=`, and before `:` character - in your case it's `53700`. So you can use one port for one task, and another port (maybe `53701`) for 2nd task...

Comment: But i cannot configure jvmoptions specific to each spark executor. spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is the single parameter for all spark executor.

Comment: sorry, you're correct... somehow thought that it's for driver :-)

Comment: I changed the answer